# Using the keyCommands method to listen for a bluetooth keyboard event

Tags: ios7

I have an application where I need to listen for a bluetooth keyboard event and set a `UITextField` as the first responder on key tap without the user having to tap on the text field to give it focus.  Currently, I have a work-around in my code to set the input text field as the first responder in an override of the `keyCommands` method on `UIApplicationDelegate`.  By experimentation, I have found that this method gets called each time the user taps on the hardware keyboard.

```
- (NSArray *)keyCommands
{
    [[self inputTextField] becomeFirstResponder];

    return _keyCommands;
}
```

***Is there any other way to listen for a hardware key tap that does not use a private API?***

While this works as of iOS 7.1, I have no confidence that my "hack-around" will continue to work with future versions of iOS.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Hi, currently I met the same issue as yours. I put [[self inputTextField] becomeFirstResponder]; in the keyCommands(). But it will be called for every UIEvent.  Do you have a decent way to handle this?